# Using fortify sca in jenkins with build tool (maven and gradle)

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, gradle, fortify

Recently, our team choose fortify sca to scan our projects.
Our projects have two types JavaEE(without EJB) and Android.

And we want to add the scan step into the CI steps.
So I add scripts like this to scan after jenkins build the project.

```
sourceanalyzer -b manage_dev -clean
sourceanalyzer -b manage_dev -jdk 1.6 -encoding UTF-8 "src/."
sourceanalyzer -b manage_dev -Xmx4000M -scan -f manage_dev_report.fpr  
ReportGenerator -format pdf -f manage_dev_report.pdf -source manage_dev_report.fpr
```

However I don't know how to set the parameter -cp(classpath) ,
due to we're using build tool the dependency libs is not inside our source code.

I know there's some maven and gradle plugin for fortify.
But we don't want to change our build scripts.

Thanks for all your helps.

Ps. We are using HP_Fortify_SCA_and_Apps_4.20, and newest version of jenkins.

Comment: Did you find any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the configuration that worked for me, in my pom.xml file:

```
<build>
    <plugins> 
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.fortify.ps.maven.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>sca-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.30</version>
            <configuration>
                <findbugs>true</findbugs>
                <htmlReport>true</htmlReport>
                <maxHeap>800M</maxHeap>
                <source>myJavaVersion</source>
                <buildId>myBuildId</buildId>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                <toplevelArtifactId>myTopLevelId</toplevelArtifactId>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

By using a single Jenkins job you can write, as a pre-step, a shell script:

```
mvn clean sca:clean -DskipTests
mvn sca:translate -DskipTests
```

And then define the actual "Goals and options" as:

```
install sca:scan -DskipTests
```

Having them as separate command lines is the only way to have the sca-clean,translate and scan (and report file sending to Fortify) done in one Jenkins job.

Hope this works for you too!

Answer (score -1):

First:

The command line is documented in the file `HP_Fortify_SCA_User_Guide_4.20.pdf`. However, the following is a common use case and a very good place to start:

The command will look like :

```
sourceanalyzer -verbose -logfile {{location where you want the log}} -XX:MaxPermSize={{perm memory size}} –Xmx{{memory to allocate}} -64 -scan -f {{file to save the result to}}  -cp {{root folder or JAR file to start crawling from}} -source {{Java version}} {{folder where source can be found}}
```

For example, this is a scan I ran on my PC:

```
sourceanalyzer -verbose -logfile "d:\TestSites\JavaVulns\mylog.txt" -XX:MaxPermSize=512M -Xmx4G -64 -scan -f MyTest.fpr  -cp "d:\TestSites\JavaVulns\*.jar" -source 1.5 d:\TestSites\JavaVulns
```

Have a great day,
Dennis